# Shift + Esc in Mathematica 13.1

Tags: front-end, keyboard, linux, version-13.1

In the previous versions of Mathematica <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd> is just interpreted as <kbd>esc</kbd>. This is quite convenient for me because, for example, capital Greek letters can be typed by keeping <kbd>shift</kbd> down and pressing <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>.

In version 13.1 this is no longer true: <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd> types this funny character: $^{\tiny{\textsf{ESC}}}$

My muscle memory is making me do the mistake $^{\tiny{\textsf{ESC}}}$D$^{\tiny{\textsf{ESC}}}$ all the time. Is there a way to go back to the old behavior?

Comment: I tried this on macOS 10.14 with Mathematica 13.1.0, and I cannot reproduce this problem. Can you update the post with information about your platform / OS and double-check that this happens only with 13.1 for you but not 13.0 (on the same system)?

Comment: It happens only on 13.1 and not 13.0 as far as I recall. I don't have a 13.0 installed so I'm 99% sure. I am on Linux x86_64

Comment: Holding down shift and hitting the sequence esc-D-esc gives me capital Delta in 13.0 and badness in 13.1, on Ubuntu 18.04 Linux.

Comment: Interesting.  I could not reproduce that behavior on Windows.  I would report this to support.

Comment: Works as expected with v13.1 on a Mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in 13.2. In the meantime, adding

```
Item[KeyEvent["Escape", Modifiers->{Shift}], "ShortNameDelimiter"]
```

to `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/KeyEventTranslations.tr`
will restore the 13.0 behaviour.